# How can i rearrange words in a div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have got a div with words seprated by a comma. How can i arrange them so there is four words per line?

edit: the words are dynamically generated

Comment: Are the only commas your word seperators?

Comment: Could you give a clue as to the mark-up around these words?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) to simplify access to the DOM:

```
var content = $('#mydiv').text();              // get current content from the page
var words = content.split(',');                // break into words
for (var i = 3; i < words.length; i += 4) {    // every fourth word (but not the first)
    words[i] += '<br>';                        // append <br>
}
content = words.join(' ');                     // and rejoin with spaces
$('#mydiv').html(content);                     // and put it back in the page
```

NB: I've used `.html()` to write the contents back out otherwise the `<br>` tags won't be rendered properly.

Comment: this sounds good. what is the jquery thing that makes the a function run after the dom is ready?

Comment: I just use `$(function() { ... } );`

Comment: if you don't want the commas at all then just replace the ',' in the "join" call with a space.  I hate late requirements changes... ;-)

Comment: this also allows an append rather than prepend, so I changed the loop slightly to accommodate that.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `<pre>...</pre>` tag. The text will appear on the screen exactly the way you have formatted it.

Comment: I have no clue what you mean by "Use the tag". Please edit your question to make it more clear.

Comment: @George - it was just bad markdown which hid his `<pre>` tag. Someone else already fixed it.

Comment: there are no line breaks in the words generated so <pre> would just print them as they are, wouldn't it

Comment: the words are dynamically generated. all in one line seperated by commas. so it wouldnt work

Answer (score 1):

Use the BR tag after every four words. See http://www.w3.org/wiki/Html/Elements/br

Answer (score 1):

If `str` contains the words, then:

```
var lines = str.match(/([^,]+,*){1,4}/g);
var output = lines === null ? '' : lines.join('<br>');
```

---

#### Example

If:

```
str = "a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i";
```

Then `output` will be:

```
"a,b,c,d,<br>e,f,g,h,<br>i"
```

Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/DH3WJ/1/).

Comment: does output contains `<br>` after every 4 words?

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery, everthing is easier. jQuery is a bunch of tools written in JavaScript and it is all saved to a variable called `$`. You can call jQuery which will call the base JavaScript for you and make life easier.

Add this to the `<head>` of your web page

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.1.min.js"></script>
```

Add `id="arrange"` to your `div`. If you don't like the word arrange, you can use any word you like. Make sure there are no spaces and only letters, numbers, underscores.

```
<div class="arrange">One two three four one two three four</div>
```

Add this anywhere after the div that has the text

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('div.arrange').each(function () { // For each div with the class="arrange"
    var words = this.innerHTML.split(/,/) // Get an array of all the words (separated by comma)
    var newHTML = '' // We will add the new contents of the div here.
    for(var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) { // For every word
        if(i != 0) {// If this is not the first word
            if(i % 4 == 0) { // If this is the fourth word
                newHTML += '<br/>' // Add a <br/>
            } else {
                newHTML += ',' // Add a comma
            }
        }
        newHTML += words[i] // Add the word
    }
    this.innerHTML = newHTML
})
</script>
```

In this case, I am using jQuery to loop through each div with `class="arrange"`

You can see a live example here: http://jsfiddle.net/gf5wD/

This example automatically includes jQuery and automatically adds the JavaScript to the end.

You will probably eventually want to save the jquery file to servers you control. The script tag in your head will call the jquery servers which means if their site goes down, yours gets messed up.

Answer (score 1):

Greetings user521180 I got you and i think this code will help

```
 function arrangeDiv() {
        var div = document.getElementById('div');
        var divinnerHTMLAry = div.textContent.split(' ');
        div.innerHTML = "";
        var divNewinnerHTML = '';
        var count = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < divinnerHTMLAry.length; i++) {
            if (divinnerHTMLAry[i] != "" && divinnerHTMLAry[i] != "\n") {
                divNewinnerHTML += divinnerHTMLAry[i] + " ";
                count += 1;
                if (count == 4) {
                    divNewinnerHTML += "<br />";
                }
            }
        }
        div.innerHTML = divNewinnerHTML;
    }
```

Regards :)

Answer (score -1):

**edit** : *this is a PHP solution*

Maybe something like that should be able to make what you want.

```
$string = 'a, b, c, d, e, f';
$array = explode(',', $string,);

foreach($array as $key => $word) {
  print trim($word);
  if ($key % 4 == 0) {
    print '<br />';
  }
}
```

If you get your word in an other way, just arrange the code so you can skip the `explode()` function.

Comment: true, i saw the tag "web development" and he's saying that the word are dynamically generated, so I **suppose** that this could be without JS

Comment: You are right, but a random guess at the language is not easily helpful.

Comment: right, I added a comment at the beginning of the post to say that this is a true PHP solution.